# How to remove/hide boot options in rEFInd bootloader screen?

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader, refind

[image: image of my bootloader screen]

I'm using dual boot Windows 11 and Fyde OS. On my bootloader screen there are 3 other boot options which are not any OS, they are EFI and recovery partition. I want only Windows and Fyde OS boot logo on my bootloader screen. The boot manager is rEFInd boot manager which got installed automatically with Fyde OS. I also have Linux environment installed on Fyde OS.

Comment: The [Using rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/refind.html)-page has information on adjusting the configuration.

Comment: `refind.conf` has all the information.